# JQM .load() /.html() content not being styled, tried all I found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've tried all i found trough internet about this, and still not working,

I have a main page where i need to load html content to a div like:

```
<div data-role="content" id="mainc">
</div>
```

The thing is, the jquerymobile css is not being aplied to the content, i've been trying around with .load triggering create event, tried with .html, nothing helped, here is some of the things i tried:

( They load the content perfectly, just the jquery styling is not applied )

```
$("#mainc").load(target, function () {
    $(this).trigger('create');
});
```

--

```
$('#mainc').load(target);
$('#mainc').trigger('create');
```

--

```
$.get(target, function(data) {
    $("#mainc").html(data);
    $('#mainc').listview('refresh');
});
```

and some more, still doing the same.

here's the result:

[image]

Comment: use `trigger('pagecreate');` it will do the job. here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qr97Y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explenation:

Your first loading method is usually correct but there's one problem, it will not work when loading only a listview. But of course there's a workaround.

### Working example:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
                $("#index").load("load.html", function() {
                    $(this).trigger("pagecreate");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">

        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### load.html

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
    <h1>Index page</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->  
</div>
```

Comment: well, the thing is, im not loading any listview, my load.html is basicaly another navbar as a submenu, what u see in image, its a navbar and not a listview: http://i.imgur.com/y84f4pX.png

Comment: Navbar is a UL list :) thats why it looks like a unstyled list.Give me a minute, I know what is your problem. I will write you a correct example.

Comment: lol true, just realized that, many thanks, i would apreciate that example :)

Comment: I have changed my example. If you are adding another navbar you must use trigger('pagecreate') because it will enhance whole page. trigger('create') will enhance only content while header and footer will stay intact.

Comment: tyvm, ill test it after lunch, ill give feedback

Comment: btw, on that example u have both navbars on the load.html, but here i have the main navbar on the index.html, and then i want to load to a div the content according to the selected. so i cant fully load the load.html to my index page div cause it will replace the alrdy placed navbar, im trying to load the pages content inside the Tap Handler of my main navbar, example:

function tapHandler(event) {
$("#mainc").load(target, function() {
         $("#index").trigger("pagecreate");
        });
}

Comment: Can you add a content of a html your are loading to your question?

Comment: i just got it to work the way i just said :) i was just missing a '#', ty vm