# jQuery Mobile Theme after php echo

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I got a .html Page with jQueryMobile. This page sends a database request to a .php script on my server. Then the script returns the result with html code and jQuery Mobile theme features like data-role="listview" included. But the JQM theme is not shown in my frontend. Only the "normal" html style of ul and li. Anyone of you know how to show the database results in jQuery theme? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dynamically adding new **`jQuery Mobile`** its content markup can only be enhanced manually through use of a proper enhancement functions. Every widget has an unique function.

This should do it:

```
$('#listviewID').listview('refresh');
```

In case this error is thrown:

> cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization

use this:

```
$('#listviewID').listview().listview('refresh');
```

There's also another solution. Instead of enhancing single component you can enhance whole content **`DIV`**, do it like this:

```
$('contentDivID').trigger('create');
```

or it can be done on a whole page like this:

```
$('pageDivID').trigger('pagecreate');
```

If you want to find more about this process (with working examples) take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, to make it transparent it is a link to my blog post.

Comment: thank you for answering! i´m not sure where to place this code. `<script>
$(document).delegate('#event', 'pageshow', function () {
    showEvents();
    $('#listview').trigger('pagecreate');
   
});
</script>`

the showEvents(); function is my ajax call to the database.

Comment: It should be executed inside a ajax success callback function. It is not enough to execute it after a function call because ajax call is async method, which means rest of the code will not wait for it to finish. That's why this must be executed when ajax load reaches success state.

Comment: `function showEvents(){
if (stadt=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("events").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("events").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://dev.tellthedj.de/db/getevents.php?q="+stadt,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}`

Comment: sry but i don´t know how to handle onsuccess. this is my function where i call my php database script -- the var "stadt" is filled with content

Comment: Then you should switch to jQuery load function or jQuery Mobile loadPage function. Both of them have callback functions. Or you can load your content inside a jQuery pagecreate event. At this point page content is still not enhanced so dynamically added content will also be enhanced.

Comment: Or learn it from here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_callback.asp this is a vanilla javascript solution.

Comment: i´m new at jq so maybe you can show me your solution in code?

Comment: Take a look at my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895229/jqm-load-html-content-not-being-styled-tried-all-i-found/16895447#16895447 there's a working example there.

Comment: i did it like this w3schools link. i inserted the refresh function after the xmlhttp.responseText. So the ajax request should be done. but still no jqm theme...

Comment: I gave you more then enough information, now it is your turn to find out how to make it work. You now understand that dynamic content must be enhanced with listview('refresh') and that this function must be executed after SUCCESSFUL ajax call.

Comment: now it works! i got it with the trigger function on success callback from xmlhttp.onreadystatechange. Thank you very much for your help!